# Azuma Hoeffding Inequality for Real valued functions on Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X1, . . . , Xn$ be i.i.d. random variables taking values in $S$ . Let $F$ be a
collection of real-valued functions on $S$ (not necessarily bounded). Define
$Z := g(X1, . . . , Xn) = \sup_{f∈F} \sum_{i=1}^n f(Xi)$. Show that $VAR[Z] ≤ 4E[\sup_{f∈F} \sum_{i=1}^n {f(Xi)}^2]$.
Suppose $\sup_{f∈F} |f| ≤ 1$, show that for all $t ≥ 0$, $\mathbf{P}(|Z − E[Z]| ≥ t\sqrt n) ≤ 2e^{−t^2/2}$.

For the first part I have no idea where that 4 is coming from. Please help.

Comment: I don't think that part 2) is true as stated (consider the case when $S =[-1,1]$ and $F$ just contains the identity function). Are you maybe missing a normalization?

Comment: Well, if the claim is incorrect for this particular $S$, you will not be able to prove it correct for a given general $S$ (since you could have $S =[-1,1]$).

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Comment: So, after normalizing can it be done?

Comment: Yes. If you divide by $\sqrt{n}$ (which should be the correct normalization), then the normalized $g$ has the bounded difference property with constant $1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Yeah, that part I got. What about the first part?